# "Ich bitte um... und..." or "Ich bitte um... und um..."

Tags: grammaticality

Is the meaning changed when I use the preposition *um* twice?

> 1. Ich bitte höflich **um** Ihre Genehmigung und **um** Anweisungen an die zuständigen Behörden zu geben, um mein obengenanntes Dokument auszustellen.
> 2. Ich bitte höflich **um** Ihre Genehmigung und Anweisungen an die zuständigen Behörden zu geben, um mein obengenanntes Dokument auszustellen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, the meaning doesn't change with or without the second *um*, **if the first and second part of the sentence have the same grammatical structure**:

> Ich bitte um Salz und [ich bitte um] Zucker.
>   Ich bitte um Salz und [ich bitte] um Zucker.

Both of the above sentences are correct and mean the same.

If the first and second part of the sentence don't follow the same grammatical pattern, you might need a different structure:

> Ich bitte um Zucker und darum, mir Salz zu geben.

This seems to be the case in your own sentences, but your examples are not correct and it's hard to understand what you're trying to say.
Since it seems to be something official, I suggest you explain it to a native speaker (in person, not online) and ask for help with the German.

Comment: You are right with your second quote. The right sentence would be: `Ich bitte höflich um Ihre Genehmigung und darum, Anweisungen an die zuständigen Behörden zu geben, um mein obengennantes Dokument auszustellen.`

Comment: "Ich bitte höflich um Ihre Genehmigung und darum Anweisungen an die zuständigen Behörden zu geben, um mein obengenanntes Dokument auszustellen." So this paragraph is understandable??

Comment: @nafmee Yes. You are asking for someone's permission, and you're asking that person to give order to the public authority to issue your document. I'd put a comma after *darum*.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. Thank you very much Philip!